Sort an array of PSCustomObject by values of a property
I need help for my sorting issue with Powershell. What I want is simple, but I'm unable to find a solution.
I do have in Powershell an array @() of PSCustomObjects like code below. First I fill the array in a loop with objects and try later to order the array.
The following simple sample should demonstrate the challange.In the real world, I receive the array from another web service.
$products = @()
for ($i -eq 1; $i -lt 50; $i++){
   $code = -join ((65..90) + (97..122) | Get-Random -Count 5 | % {[char]$_})

   $value = [PSCustomObject]@{ }
   $value | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ProductId -Value $i
   $value | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ProductCode -Value $code
   $products += $value
}

# other try
# for ($i -eq 1; $i -lt 50; $i++){
#     $code = -join ((65..90) + (97..122) | Get-Random -Count 5 | % {[char]$_})
#     $value = [PSCustomObject]@{ ProductId=$i; ProductCode="$code"}
#     $products += $value
# }

Write-Host $products | Sort-Object -Property ProductCode

I expect a result like this, sorted by ProductCode:
@{ProductId=4; ProductCode=ashku} @{ProductId=1; ProductCode=Ahjju} 
@{ProductId=3; ProductCode=bBhhg} @{ProductId=2; ProductCode=qtras} 
@{ProductId=5; ProductCode=yYfgh}

Has anyone the solution for me? Thanks in advance.
Tino

So why is the Write-Host there? It's what's causing your issue.

write-host converts the object to a string

Write-Host ($products | Sort-Object -Property ProductCode) <-- ensure the data is sorted before it's passed to Write-Host

As an aside: Write-Host is typically the wrong tool to use, unless the intent is to write to the display only, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it by itself; e.g., $value instead of Write-Host $value (or use Write-Output $value, though that is rarely needed). See also: the bottom section of this answer.

CLARIFICATION: Write-Host doesn't send its output to the Success Stream but directly to the Host(usually the terminal) so Sort-Object receives nothing to sort.
Original:
As explained in the comments: the problem is Write-Host converting the elements to strings before sorting them.
Also Write-Host is specifically used to send information to the user through the console, but it's mostly meant for strings.
You might want to pipe the results to Format-Table or Format-List instead.
Here a working example(with optimized production of the example code because your was really inefficient)
$products = foreach ($i in 1..50) {
    $code = -join ((65..90) + (97..122) | Get-Random -Count 5 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ })
    [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        ProductId   = $i
        ProductCode = $code
    }
}

$products | Sort-Object -Property ProductCode | Format-List

this will return
 ProductId ProductCode
 --------- -----------
            
        36 AdmCc
        42 BhQpU
        37 BVSbw
        24 cusnH
        35 DsSrp
        27 EWokb
        30 fiuKF
         5 gBmPA
        21 gxnOe
        39 HDgyr
        48 hEwHA
         8 hHSXE
         6 HoTsJ
         3 iLMUv
        10 IWCru
        14 iySPg
        15 JgVyp
        20 JlziB
        18 jRfGo
        44 JuAcq
        33 kmZRO
        43 KZTHp
        47 lgumS
        29 lKyZg
        40 LqKFc
        28 McGjW
        16 mHvhg
        38 nGBLm
        32 nmekO
        12 NRJvw
        11 oZnRc
        23 pbMvq
         2 PLDgT
        19 PoeXl
        41 pSiDN
         7 ptUfA
        26 qxQSv
         9 rCwnE
        13 RMqFT
         1 SPJrz
        22 TDvWC
        50 UFbuM
        34 uVCIA
        49 VvflM
        25 vzpwT
        45 wPJtp
        31 WxcTk
         4 XgFIG
        17 xGrRz
        46 XRTnr


@zett42 I updated the solution, thank you

Thank you for your help. I did not know that sorting is not executed by Write-Host.
